# i have a login table though which i authenticate a user.I want <li> item to be shown which is hidden during prelogin how to do it in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<li class="active"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li style="display:none;"><a class="drop" href="#">Articles</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Category.aspx">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="PopularArticles.aspx">Popular Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="MostReadArticles.aspx">Most Read</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to display the articles list item on successful login

Answer (score 0):

Make your parent `li` as server control using  `runat="server"` and also provide a unique id somthing like `id="liAfterLogin"`.

**HTML Change**

```
 <li style="display:none;" runat="server" id="liAfterLogin"><a class="drop" href="#">Articles</a>

            <ul>

              <li><a href="Category.aspx">Categories</a></li>

              <li><a href="PopularArticles.aspx">Popular Articles</a></li>

              <li><a href="MostReadArticles.aspx">Most Read</a></li>

            </ul>

          </li>
```

**Code behind change**

place this code within login function and after where you identify successful login.

```
liAfterLogin.Style.Add("display", "block");
```

Comment: Satish sam: but sir that list item id is on master page and that login is a content page. it is not able to find the control of the master page on login page? how to find that control on login page

Comment: u can find the masterpage html  control within login page. `step-1:` include `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` namespace. `Step 2:`- `Find and typecast control` `HtmlGenericControl myUl = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("yourControlID");`. `Step 3- ` use `myUI` as you want

Comment: you can treat `myUI' variable as local page control

Comment: con.Open();
            string checkPassword = "SELECT Password FROM AdminLoginDetailsTbl WHERE UserID='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmdpwd = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, con);
            string password = cmdpwd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            HtmlGenericControl myUI = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("liAfterLogin");

            if (password == TextBoxPWD.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxUN.Text;
                myUI.Style.Add("display","block");
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }

Comment: satish sam:sir have user it like this but it still does not show the  article block

Comment: Please debug what u are getting in myUI